# How to get the day value out of a textbox in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

For example, if the textbox contains 11/11/2016 OR 01/05/2016
How to get the day value only? example. 11 OR 01

Comment: Convert the string to a `DateTime` and reference that object's `.Day` property?

Comment: this is definitely not that difficult what have you tried besides just posting this question.. ? have you even tried a simple google search or researched the DateTime Struct..?

Comment: Does 01/05/2016 mean January 5th or May 1st?

Comment: @StingyJack He already posted the result as 01. So that would be the first of May.

Comment: @user3185569 - too indirect, fair enough. Are you sure all your users will assume that you mean to use US style dates?

Comment: Anyway, this is almost too easy to be asked

Answer (score 2):

One way is to parse the string in the TextBox to DateTime using an exact format. Then using the DateTime object, you can extract the `Day` Property:

```
DateTime date;

bool success = DateTime.TryParseExact(textBoxDate.Text, "dd/MM/yyyy", 
                                      CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, 
                                      DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal, out date);
int day;
if(success)
{
    day = date.Day; // 1
    // or string stringDay = date.ToString("dd"); to get 01
}
else
{
    // handle error
}
```

Another way that I don't prefer (Not 100% safe input validation) is to use `String.Split` like this:

```
string strDay = textBoxDate.Text.Split('/').FirstOrDefault();
int day;
if(Int32.TryParse(strDay, out day))
{
    // success
}
else
{
    // Handle Error
}
```

Answer (score -3):

```
string myString = textbox1.text; 

DateTime day = DateTime.ParseExact(myString, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

int day = birthday.Day;
```